# I want the presentview and its contents to be on scroll view when orientation occurs to landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

when i shift from portrait mode to landscape mode the view should expand widely but the length should be the same and in scrollview so that when i scroll the fullcontents should be displayed:

```
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 480)];
    view1 = self.view;
    [scrollView addSubview:view1];
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 480);
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 480);
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

Comment: can anyone send the code for it

Comment: Google it, try something before asking

Comment: i hav tried it but cant able to expand the view and display it ...

Comment: Show the code you have tried with.

Comment: if(([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    UIScrollView * scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 480)];
    view1 = self.view;
    [scrollView addSubview:view1];
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 480);
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 480);
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) { 
UIScrollView * scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] init]; UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 480)]; 
view1 = self.view; [scrollView addSubview:view1]; scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 480);           
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 480); scrollView.delegate = self; 
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES; [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with more information for example - what is and is not working? Don't add updates as comments, edit your question.

In your existing code, at least this is wrong/confused:

```
 UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 480)];
 view1 = self.view;
```

you are assigning a pointer to a new view in the first line, then reassigning it to your existing self.view in the second line. Then here:

```
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

you are adding a scrollview containing a content view to that same content view. That's not going to work.

As a cleaner solution, why don't you set up your scrollview/subview combo for *both* orientations. Then when you rotate, you just need to alter your scrollview's contentsize.

For the normal upright orientation:

```
            self.scrollview.contentSize = self.scrollview.bounds.size;
```

For landscape:

```
              self.scrollview.contentSize =
         CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.contentView.bounds.size.height
```

(assuming your content is in a view called contentView contained inside your scrollView)

You should be able to get the `contentOffset` to work correctly for both orientations in the storyboard, but if not your can set it in code for each orientation.